Как перенести бд sql с помощью скрипта в файле по крону на другой хостинг. Подскажите куда копать?
Как перенести бд c помощью скрипта sql и php, подскажите куда копать, уже долго ищу в гугле, но не нашёл примера или объяснений?

а зачем для переноса БД на другой хостинг использовать php, sql и cron, в чем необходимость их использования? обычно достаточно сделать дамп БД (mysqldump/mysqlpump), скопировать его на другой сервер и развернуть (mysql < dump.sql). Есть еще репликация, но это вряд ли ваш случай.

"скрипта sql" не бывает в принципе. И по крону не переносят. Посему задача не ясна - нужно перенести или таки что-то постоянно делать по крону.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы на сайт клон каждую неделю обновлялось бд по крону и файлы

Это называется репликация и в зависимости от БД настраивается по разному.

Благодарю, на хостинге есть услуга репликации бд, а вот как файлы обновлять автоматически из оригинального сайта в клон буду разбираться дальше
